# Realm.GetInstanceAsync(_realmConfiguration) SSL server certificate rejected

Tags: .net-core, realm

I have taken Realm for a spin on net-core.

I am using the latest build which is [10.0.0-beta.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Realm/10.0.0-beta.3)

This is my code

```
        var appConfig = new AppConfiguration("xxxxxxxxxx")
        {
            LocalAppName = "MongoDbTest",
            LocalAppVersion = "1.1.1"
        };


        //_realmApp = App.Create("xxxxxxxxx");

        try
        {
            _realmApp = App.Create(appConfig);
            var user = _realmApp.LogInAsync(Credentials.Anonymous()).Result;
            _realmConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration("MyPartition", user, "MyRealmData");
            _realm = Realm.GetInstanceAsync(_realmConfiguration).Result;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("****** Login succeeded");
        }
```

I am getting an `AggregateException` with the `InnerException` of "SSL server certificate rejected"

Anyone can please point me to what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression with beta.3. You can downgrade to beta.2 or wait until the regression is fixed with a future release.

Comment: Many thanks @Nikola. I already came across on the MongoDb developer community thread [link](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/realm-10-0-0-beta-3-ssl-error-on-call-to-realm-getinstanceasync-config/12851/6). I have tried with beta.2. But then the `GetInstanceAsync` hangs forever not returning control to the calling code.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is a poor platform to debug such issues on. My advice would be to either open a [Github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues) or create a new forum thread outlining the problem and ideally, providing a repro case.